# GoogleSignIn stopped working - the responseCode in onActivityResult is 0

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

My code for GoogleSignin is not working, though there is no error following is happeing:

- the code is getting compiled.
- Moreover when I click on sign-in I get a popup asking me which google account I want to sign in with.
- The `responseCode` in `onActivityResult` is `0`.

It was working pretty fine till yesterday, but I was facing some issues while generating Signed APK, so upgraded my Android Studio (3.3.1), changed a little bit of gradle - and now GoogleSignin is not working.

Spent a day on this, but have not been able to crack the issue. I am not well versed with Android programming and would appreciate any help.

The relevant code is pasted below. In case more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks.

P.S.:
 - The `signInIntent` in `startActivityForResult` & `intent` in `onActivityResult` are different. Probably that's fine - thought to highlight just in case.

The start activity is:

```
private void signIn() {
    if(!isSignedIn()) {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN_ONLY_ID);
    }
}
```

The result activity is:

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                 Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN_ONLY_ID:
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_ONLY_ID, responseCode="
                    + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
           Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);
            handleSignInResult(task);
            break;
```

The gradle:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
    }

    dependencies {
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
//    mavenLocal()
 //   mavenCentral()
  //  google()        //---> Add this
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/.../androidkey.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
        }
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/.../androidkey.jks')
            storePassword 'xxx'
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goSkill.earn"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.0098"
        multiDexEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            //debuggable true
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    api 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up OAuth client ID for the project? This requires you to create OAuth Client ID, and provide SHA-1 of your keystore.

Google SignIn usually returns with `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED` when you did not.

Follow [this instruction](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=pl#installedapplications&android) if you didn't.

Comment: That was the issue. Had changed the package name too while making other changes. Thank you.